# Pre-populate "Send Payment" data on PayPal?

Tags: paypal

Is there a way to pre-populate the "Send Payment" data on PayPal? I don't wan't a pay now button, I just want to be able to have a button for my own internal use that launches the Paypal website and pre populates the fields to send a payment to somebody.  Is that possible?

I've tried using a form that submits the data to paypal, but I have a problem, the AMOUNT field doesn't populate, and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong!

This is what I have so far:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target = "paypal">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_send-money">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="email" VALUE="someone@gmail.com">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="currency_code" VALUE="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="15.00">
<input type="submit" value="Open Paypal">
</form>
```

Comment: What fields do you want to prepopulate?

Comment: @Dennis I updated my question, I need to get the payment amount to be passed on to PayPal.

Comment: I tested your code and it works for me as-is .. "15.00" is filled out on the paypal.com page

Comment: @PrestonAlexander I have tested it, and someone else has, it fills it out as long as you are not logged in.  If you are logged in, it doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try redirecting to the paypal.me/accountname/moneyamount (example: paypal.me/johnsmith/50) to have it bring you to a page that pays the john smith account with a pre-filled amount of $50. This functionality is set up by default.
https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Products-and-Services/Can-the-PayPal-me-URL-be-modified-to-pre-fill-the-quot-Note-quot/td-p/1509015